# Dynamic select fluent nhibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, fluent-nhibernate

First of all, sorry for my bad english.

I have a little trobule figurering this one out.
I have three tables and I need to make it so that the user can decide witch columns to fetch from the database.
I have tried using Dynamic nuget, but wont work.
The code i need is something like the line below.

```
var res = session.QueryOver<MyObject>().Select(x => x.decidedByUser).List();
```

Is this even possible or do I need to make some kind of workaround? Maybe something like getting all the values and then select? :-)

Comment: Just take them all and decide which you want to display on client side code

Answer (score 0):

var columnProjection = Projections.Property(() => aliasForTable.Column1)

you can use above variable in nhibernate select statement to decide which column you want to fetch. Create this assignment for each of your case and you're done